# Problem displaying image in Latex exactly where I want it

Tags: floats

Im having trouble displaying an image. It tends to float where ever it wants in the doc. The code I used it displayed here

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=8cm]{Hyperfine_splitting.png}
\end{center}
\caption{\label{fig1} Hyperfine splitting of hydrogen states. The first three states equivalent to $F=1$ and the single state corresponding to $F=0$}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please provide a specific example of the "tends to float where ever it wants" case. How far away does the `figure` environment float? Incidentally, how tall is the entire `figure`? Incidentally, if you want a simple way of economizing on vertical space, replace `\begin{center}` with `\centering` and delete `\end{center}`.

Comment: @Mico the image tends to float to the last section in the document. Also im not really sure what you mean by how tall is the figure?

Comment: @Ritu Kelkar The primary problem ist that you question as it is currently written is unsolveable. The code you provided is perfectly fine once a proper `\documentclass{}` is added and {Hyperfine_splitting.png} is exchanged with {example-image-a} since nobody has you image. Also without knowing your packages laoded (or documentclass) it is a big guessing game. Read the link I provided earlier. It basically handles your problem.

Comment: the only reason to use `\begin{figure}` is to allow it to move, but using `[h]` makes it moving to the end of the document quite likely as it removes the possibilities `t b p` so  does not allow the float at the top of a page, the bottom of a page or on a page  of just floats, which does not give many places it is allowed.  latex will warn about this and change it to  `ht` to give itself a chance but preventing `p` floats is still very restrictive and force larger images to the end of the document

Comment: use `\centering` not `\begin{center}` and use `[htbp]` not `[!h]`

Comment: if `[h!]` float is  because cannot be fitted in the actual page, and the  alternative to fix only  here  (`[H]` of float package)  is much worse: jump anyway to the next page but now leaving a huge bottom space on the previous page. Bad solution: use [H] and bear with the ragged bottoms. Good solutions: move the float or resize the image so it can be fitted without floating, or better allow floating (see above comment) and use  `\ref` and `\pageref`,  that exist just to locate something that is "lost" in another page.